# How to introduce quadratic residues?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, education, motivation

What is the most motivating way to introduce quadratic residues? I would like some concrete examples which have an impact. This is for first-year undergraduates doing an elementary number theory course. They have done Diophantine equations, solved linear congruences, primitive roots.

Comment: As with ordinary algebra, having looking at linear equations it is surely natural to move up to quadratics.  Outside of characteristic $2$, that ends up being largely a matter of extracting square roots, hence quadratic residues and non-residues comes up immediately.

Comment: Maybe ask instead on math educators stackexchange?

Answer (score 1):

I like to build the quadratic part of elementary number theory on the Diophantine equation
$$
x^2 + dy^2 = n.
$$
When $n$ is prime a necessary condition is that $-d$ is a quadratic residue.

You can start this study with the case $d = 1$. When does $-1$ have a square root modulo a prime $p$? That's approachable without too much machinery. Lots of good history.